# How to export 2d array into Excel sheets using python using Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, export-to-excel

I am trying to write a array into Excel spreadsheet using Python

the array looks something like this:

```
array = [ [N1,N2,N3], [N4,N5,N6], [N7,N8,N9], [N10, N11, N12]]
```

As the spread sheet should look like this:

```
N1  N2  N3 
N4  N5  N6 
N7  N8  N9  
N10 N11 N12
```

However my code:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(array).T   
result.to_excel('clean_data.xlsx')
```

give the result of

```
N1  N4  N7 N10
N2  N5  N8 N11
N3  N6  N9 N12
```

Can anyone show the Python code to do it ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't transpose `result = pd.DataFrame(array)`

Comment: I have already mentioned in the code above, i.e. `result = pd.DataFrame(array)` instead of `result = pd.DataFrame(array).T`. Notice `.T` which transposes the dataframe.

Comment: @ThePyGuy oh, I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You transpose the matrix/array by doing the

> .T

thus your results is orientated differently:

simply doing without the transformation gives your desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

array = [ ["N1","N2", "N3"], ["N4", "N5","N6"], ["N7","N8","N9"], ["N10", "N11", "N12"]]
result = pd.DataFrame(array) #remove the .T here
result.to_excel('clean_data.xlsx')
```